# how to create a vector that has a fixed number of points per decade?

Tags: list-manipulation, logarithmic-scale

How do I create a frequency vector that increments the step size as a percentage of the previous step size? For example, if I wanted to create table, and wanted to span 4 decades with 100 point in each decade, how would I define that?

Comment: Have you seen [`PowerRange`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerRange.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your table:

```
Table[x, {x, 10^Range[0, 4, 1/100]}]
```

Comment: Wait, why aren't you just doing `10^Range[0, 4, 1/100]`?

Comment: Because the OP wanted to have a table so I provided the code where he only needs to insert his function in place of `x`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it later this morning.  However, doesn't this make each step 10^(1/100)?  I'm looking to make each step 10^(1/100)*(previous step).  Still trying it when I get into the office- thanks!

Comment: works like a charm.  Thank you.  I understand it now.  Excellent.